# How can I call a function in C++ when I get the WinRT/UWP error 'Activating a single-threaded class from MTA is not supported?'

Tags: c++, windows, com, uwp, sta

When attempting to call a single-threaded apartment (STA) function from the "wrong" thread (*e.g.*, `Clipboard::SetContent(...)`), I see the following message:

> Activating a single-threaded class from MTA is not supported.

It's not obvious which functions are STA, so it just seems to jump out from seemingly innocent-looking functions. I couldn't find a simple answer that explains the steps to fix it. The Windows COM documentation is difficult to follow.

How can I reliably identify what is a STA function in order to prevent this error? Isn't there a simple fix?

Comment: Quote: "This class is not agile, which means that you need to consider its threading model and marshaling behavior. For more info, see ...".  Maybe it sounds gobbledegooky but after a while you'll see the connection between the docs and the exception.  With the link in the "see" note telling you what to do about it.

Comment: Yes, I waded through all of that which is how I came up with the answer below. The point of adding this question was to spare others that trauma when they tread on the STA/MTA landmine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the thread you're currently running on is MTA (multi-threaded apartment), and doesn't support STA calls.

The fix is to dispatch the call from the main/UI thread, which is always STA and therefore supports STA calls.

First, get the thread you want with `MainView->CoreWindow`, and then call that thread's dispatcher to invoke whatever it was you wanted to run. For example:

```
using namespace Windows::UI::Core;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Core;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer;

CoreWindow^ window = CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow;        
window->Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
    ref new DispatchedHandler
    (
        [wstringForClipboard]
        {
            DataPackage^ clipboardInfo = ref new DataPackage;
            clipboardInfo->SetText(ref new Platform::String(wstringForClipboard.c_str()));
            Clipboard::SetContent(clipboardInfo);
        }
   )
);
```

Comment: If you h ave resolved your issue please mark it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.